# The #if elif directives not working as desired

Tags: c++

I am trying to test a condition using if elif but I am not getting the desired results. Please help me in identifying what i am doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define a(t1)(t1+50)
#define b(t2)(t2+100)
int main()
{
    union gm
    {
        int t1;
        int t2;
    };
    gm c;

    cout <<"Enter tokens earned in game 1: "<<endl;
    cin>>c.t1;
    int x=c.t1;
    cout <<"Enter tokens earned in game 2: "<<endl;
    cin>>c.t2;
    int y=c.t2;
    int m= a(x)+100;
    int n= b(y)+50;
    int p;
    p=m+n;
    cout <<p<<endl;

#if(p<500)
    cout <<"Points earned too less"<<endl;
#elif (p>500 && p<1500)
    cout<<"You can play game 1 free"<<endl;
#elif (p>1500 && p<2500)
    cout<<"You can play game 1 free"<<endl;
#elif p>3000
    cout<<"You can play game 1 and game free"<<endl;
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

When the value of P is exceeding 500, still showing message "Points earned too less".

Please help.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use preprocessor macros that depend on the value of a variable at run time.

Unless `p` is defined to be preprocessor macro,

```
#if(p<500)
```

is translated as:

```
#if(0<500)
```

Since that is true, only that block of code is compiled into object code. That explains the behavior you are seeing.

You need to use the `if-else` statements of C++, not the preprocessor.

```
if (p<500)
{
   cout <<"Points earned too less"<<endl;
}
else if (p>500 && p<1500)
{
   cout<<"You can play game 1 free"<<endl;
}
else if (p>1500 && p<2500)
{
   cout<<"You can play game 1 free"<<endl;
}
else if ( p>3000 )
{
   cout<<"You can play game 1 and game free"<<endl;
}
else
{
   // Do something for everything else.
}
```